# Rails 3: form validation doesn't work after using jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I used jQuery-File-Upload from [blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), the form validation error message disappear in my page. It gives me a upload error message instead.

I think it might be overwritten by the Query-File-Upload.

This is my code in `_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @upload, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fileupload"  } do |f| %>
      <% if @upload.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@upload.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this from being saved:</h2>
            <ul>
              <% @upload.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                  <li><%= msg %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
      <% end %>
.....
```

Any ideas how to bring the validation message back?

**Update:**

I found out that the validation error message is actually generated but somehow the file upload plugin prevents it from displaying.

the most suspicious part is this code in `uploads_controller`:

```
def create
    @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
        format.html { render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, :content_type => 'text/html',:layout => false }
        format.json { render json: [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

When the validation fails, it went into the `else` statement and render something in json, however it is not displayed on the form.

Should I change the way it renders?

Comment: change `upload_controller.rb` to `uploads_controller.rb` and on `_form.html.erb` using `@upload`

Comment: no it doesn't work. Instead I changed something so that I can use @upload in my form now, but the validation message still doesn't show up